# Simulate phone call on hands-free to play audio files with AVAudioPlayer

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Many older cars have no option to play music from external bluetooth devices (A2DP), they are only able to handle phone calls (hands free). But some navigation apps are able to play sounds simulating a phone call. This way, the radio/CD-player gets interrupted as long as the navigation app plays the sound.
Has anyone an idea how to do this with AVAudioPlayer? Or another method? I could not find any infos related.

That's what I have so far, but I guess I'm completely wrong..

```
NSUInteger optionsFlag = (AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionAllowBluetooth | AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers | AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDuckOthers);

[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback withOptions:optionsFlag error: nil];

NSURL *soundFileURL = @"/path/to/soundfile.wav";      
player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL error:nil];
[player play];
```

Comment: You've added AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers, which literally means not to do the thing you're asking for. Is there a reason you've asked it to mix if you want it to pause?

Comment: @RobNapier I already tried without AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers but it has no effect on my car-audio system. I should have mentioned my car audio system has no "bluetooth-aux" option to play audio from any source. The bluetooth connection is only for hands-free telephone calls. When a navigation app plays a sound, the car display says "phone call active". So there must be some trick to play sounds like a telephone call.

Comment: When you say without AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers, did you also remove ...DuckOthers? Ducking implies mixing. Just use AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionAllowBluetooth.